# How to drop a column from a csv file when reading into a spark dataframe

Tags: csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I am trying to create a spark dataframe from a csv file however i do not want to include a particular column from the raw data in the dataframe. Is this possible when setting up the schema or when reading in the csv file?

Answer (score 4):

The `drop` answer by @Manu Valdés is the best way to go, here is the code with `pyspark`

Suppose we have a `file.csv` with 3 columns :

```
col1;col2;col3
val1;val2;val3
val4;val5;val6
```

Now read the csv file with `sqlContext` :

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true', delimiter=';').load('/FileStore/file.csv')

df.printSchema()

root 
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
```

Drop `col2` :

```
df2 = df.drop('col2')
df2.printSchema()

root 
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: is it possible to drop the column as you're reading the csv in as opposed to after the dataframe has been created?

Comment: it's possible with the data schema definition, but the column to delete must be at the end of the csv file

Comment: the best method is to use `drop('col2')` or `select('col1', 'col3')`

Comment: If you prefer RDD, then you can drop column before creating a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame method `drop` returns a DataFrame without the indicated column.